# Are there any RIA Frameworks which allow me to use C++?

Tags: c++, rich-internet-application

I have written an simple applications in C++, and I need to connect with any RIA just for viewing the process ... is there is any good RIA based on C++

Comment: We need more specifics on what you need to do. Are you trying to implement the server side of the application in C++? Or are you trying to control a web application written by somebody else, and you would like to do so using C++?

Comment: i have written an apps in c++ and i need to control the application from the web application like if i need to start the apps while i click the button like that

Comment: Okay, so you want someone to be able to run your C++ application in browser?

Answer (score 1):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com) is a good, popular cross-platform GUI library for C++.

I don't know whether it matches your definition of "RIA", though.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight is the nearest framework for you. You may find this Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478911/silverlight-and-c-or-c-to-c-ongoing-code-conversion) interesting.

**Update**

After seeing your comment, I'd recommend you using [ISAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Server_Application_Programming_Interface) or [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) programming in C or C++

**Update 2**

After figuring that you need to execute C++ code from browsers, The answer is [ActiveX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX). But portability is an issue, rather.

Comment: but i need it in linux based not windows based

Comment: @rajesh: Silverlight works just fine on Linux boxes (It's called Moonlight for Linux boxes). And Silverlight does not care what kind of server you are using in any case. But @mmonem: Silverlight cannot be used with C++, so I don't see how it's relevant here.

Comment: @Billy, At least you can call a C++ dll from it

Comment: @mmonem: Not as far as I am aware. Silverlight requires that the code it executes be able to run as partially trusted code. C++/CLI, the dialect of C++ for the CLR, cannot generate partially trusted code unless you compile with the /pure option, which disallows **all** native C++ features, such as pointers, and requires you to use managed classes and references instead. (Because with pointers you could break the integrity of the execution environment) Anything resembling C++ is stripped away at that point.

Comment: @Bill: I agree! but don't you see that if the asker really needs RIA framework then Silverlight would be the nearest? nerear than Java and Flash.

Comment: @mmonem: Not really. C++/CLI is very similar to a poor imitation of Java. No C++ idioms operate there; you have to treat the language like it is C# -- it has C# semantics, not C++ ones. I suppose it's slightly closer, but close only counts in horse shoes and hand grenades :)

Comment: @Billy: Thanks for the +1 but please let me know what is a SCITE answer and forgive my Englishness :P

Comment: @mmonem: Nothing to do with "Englishness" :) It's from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19535#19535 Basically I'm saying that because I posted an answer about ActiveX before you edited that into your answer.

Comment: @Billy: Oops! I am blushed! but I swear didn't see your post about ActiveX

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/)? It comes with [Webkit](http://webkit.org/) [built-in](http://qt.nokia.com/products/library/modular-class-library#info_webkit). It is also more portable than other RIA implementations. BTW, most RIA implementations run on language virtual machines that are in turn implemented in C or C++ :-)

Comment: RIA is about getting your application to run inside the browser, not about embedding a browser inside your application.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this is difficult to do. Clients don't trust running arbitrary C++ code from the internet, because people don't want every website under the sun to be able to install malware, and generally hijack the entire machine, every time they visit a web site. In the general case, therefore, what you want is not really possible.

If you're willing to require the user to answer a ton of prompts, and are okay restricting your application to Internet Explorer on Windows, you could familiarize yourself with COM and write an ActiveX control.

I would strongly advise against doing so, however.

Comment: i am not doing this for an website its for my web application and its only for internal use

Comment: @rajesh: Err.. then why are you trying to run the application in browser? Is it really all that difficult for your users to download the binary first?